# git difftool with -I option

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-difftool

Since git 2.30, we have the option to specify ignore patterns in git diff. However, I can't get the `-I` option working with `git difftool`.

#### Example

Let's say I add a line with `text`.

```
git diff -I"text"
```

returns nothing, as expected.

However,

```
git difftool -I"text"
```

opens up the diff tool with the change including `text`.

My first thought was that maybe the `-I` argument is completely ignored in `difftool` command, but I can confirm that the command is trying to parse the regex:

```
git difftool -I"*text"
```

returns

```
error: invalid regex given to -I: '*text'
```

`git difftool` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) implies that all `git diff` options are inherited:

> See git-diff[1] for the full list of supported options.

Options `-G` and `-S` behave the same for `git diff` and `git difftool`, so my expectation was similar for `-I`.

Why is there a discrepancy between the results of `git diff -I` and `git difftool -I`?

Comment: It looks like the `-I` filtering happens "too late", so that when using difftool, Git runs the chosen tool on the differing files before deciding whether the files still differ after filtering away ignored matches. This is either a bug, or an undocumented feature. :-)

Comment: @torek I am more inclined towards a bug, given that `-G` option works the same way for both `git diff` and `git difftool`.

Comment: I used git trace and dug into the source code. It looks like `git difftool` is calling `git diff --raw` behind the scenes and `--raw` doesn't work with the `-I`. This is true for other ignore patterns too such as `--ignore-blank-lines`.